# How to open userform using VBA on a Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2010

I am doing a small VBA script and testing it on a PC, which works great, but as soon as I put it on a MAC, it doesn't work anymore.

What I am trying to do is to save the name of a userform in variable, and opening it using VBA:

```
Dim curForm As Object
Dim UserFormName as String
UserFormName = "myUserForm"
Set curForm = UserForms.Add(UserFormName)
curForm.Show
```

The error I get is "Invalid Procedure call or Argument", I am guessing it's complaining because UserForms.Add does not exist on a Mac, what should I do?

Comment: VBA.  Did you create a userform first called "myUserForm", I am just using that name as an example.

Comment: Ahhh oops. Nevermind!

Comment: Does the form contain ActiveX controls? I think that is a problem for Mac (but I do not have a Mac to test).

Comment: It does not.  And the error happens direct on the line "Set curForm = UserForms.Add(UserFormName)" so I know for a fact that it's a problem with the UserForms.Add function not exisiting on a Mac.